# Framing interior non-bearing wall with 24" on center for sound proofing

Tags: code-compliance, framing, sound-proofing

I'd like to sound proof a few interior walls in my house using the techniques for the 52 STC here (http://www.soundproofingcompany.com/soundproofing-solutions/soundproofing-walls/) which is basically 24" o.c. framing with R13 insulation and doubled 5/8" drywall with green glue product in between and acoustic chalk and putty pads.

My question is can I build a 2x4 stud wall with 24" on center and meet code? I'm in North Carolina.

Comment: If these walls are not yet built/framed, there are a few techniques the site you link does not mention - such as using offset studs (24" O.C. on each side of the wall, but each stud only touches one wall face and they are 12 OC on the header/footer - either by using 2x3 studs or 2x6 plates - fill with insulation) and mounting the drywall faces on resilient channel. If you are just adding to the face of a wall, these things are hard to retrofit - if you are framing it from scratch, they are easy and can be quite effective.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Do you think from a sound perspective there is much difference between 2x4 plates with 2x3 studs or 2x6 with 2x4 studs? I don't have a huge house so I want to keep the walls as thin as possible but the wall separates the master bedroom from a kids bedroom and I want it to be as sound proof as needed.

Comment: The thicker wall would allow more insulation, but given the fact that you'd like to keep the wall as thin as possible, the 2x4 & 2x3 version is still an improvement over a solid 2x4. For a bit more detail if you can handle mm measurements, here's a nice link from Canada. http://www.nrc-cnrc.gc.ca/ctu-sc/files/doc/ctu-sc/ctu-n1_eng.pdf Also, try to find "old heavy" 5/8" type X, not "new lightweight" 5/8" type X - for sound control, heavy is good, as pointed out in that link.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Thanks for the link. I think I'm going to go with the 2x4 w/ 2x3 24" offset 12" oc, R13 in the walls, resilient channel on one side and doubled up 5/8" heavy with green glue between them. I might bypass the resilient channel depending on thickness.

Answer (score 1):

Yes drywall is rated for 24 oc.